# Opening a .jar in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, desktop, archive

While making a game, i moved from programming in windows to ubuntu for better usability. that aside, when in windows, using `Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();` and using `d.open(new File("file dir.jar");` and it worked in windows. but, when using ubuntu, it opens the jar in an archive manager. so my question is, how would i open the .jar to be executed? Any help would be great! thanks in advance!

**Edit:** it may be possible i installed java wrong... but i did it the way i found on google. if that is the case, any correction would be great :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two ways:

1) add the jar you want to run to the program classpath and run it's main method.

2) using [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) you can run anything you want, but you may lose platform independence

Comment: the program is in the same exact place as the running jar. how would i use runtime.exec() to be compatible with ubuntu and mac?

Comment: `System.getRuntime().exec("java -jar app.jar")` (+handling all the possible exceptions)

Comment: it's giving me the error: `The method getRuntime() is undefined for the type System`

Comment: sorry, it is `Runtime.getRuntime()`

Answer (score 1):

The archive manager is set as the default program to open .jar files. You will have to change it in Ubuntu's settings for default programs. You can right-click on the file you want to open and select to open it with your installed Java runtime environment, in the meantime.

Comment: well i already tried that actually XD and it didnt really work... mainly because i was unable to set the default to Oracle Java 7... only Oracle Java 7 web start, which was the wrong one, i even tried using it...